# Error running tutorial that came along wxPython2.8 Docs and Demos

Tags: python, windows, wxpython

I tried the following example code from the tutorial that came along "wxPython2.8 Docs and Demos" package.

```
import wx

from frame import Frame

class App(wx.App):
    """Application class."""

    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = Frame()
        self.frame.Show()
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        return True

def main():
    app = App()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

but its giving me the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Documents and Settings/umair.ahmed/Desktop/wxpy.py", line 3, in <module>
    from frame import Frame
ImportError: No module named frame
```

kindly help i am just a newbie with python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should skip the "from frame import Frame" and change:

```
self.frame = Frame()
```

to:

```
self.frame = wx.Frame()
```

Comment: Thanx. But i needed to change self.frame = Frame() to self.frame = wx.Frame(None)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's an ancient doc bug, see for example [this 5-years-old post](http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Python/comp.lang.python/2004-02/4023.html):-(. Fix:

- delete the line that says `from frame
  import Frame`
- change the line that says `self.frame
  = Frame()` to say instead `self.frame = wx.Frame()`